# Passing parameters using .call() inside a setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, setinterval

What I am trying to do is make a function that calls another function continuously as long as the mouse button is being held. I am doing this just so I can get a better understanding of .call() and callbacks. Here is my code:

```
jQuery.fn.contmousedown = function(mousedownCallback){
  var interval, self = this;
  jQuery(this).mousedown(function(event){
    interval = setInterval(function(self, event){
      mousedownCallback.call(self, event);
      console.log('on');
    },0);
  });
  jQuery(this).mouseup(function(event){
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
}

$(document).contmousedown(function(e){
  $('#run').html(e.pageX+', '+e.pageY);
});
```

And the error I receive is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined
```

And of course I am receiving that about 300x a second. :) If i change my interval declaration line to `interval = setInterval(function(self){` then I get 'on' logged to my console at about 300x a second but I lose the event. So my question is how can I make it so I can callback the function and pass it the event parameter?

[**Example - http://jsfiddle.net/ZxKxD/**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxKxD/)

---

Thinking about this on my commute home, I decided that it would be nice to keep both events. So here is my final code:

```
jQuery.fn.mousehold = function(mousedownCallback){
  var interval, self = this, move_event;
  jQuery(this).mousemove(function(e){
    move_event = e;
  });
  jQuery(this).mousedown(function(click_event){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      mousedownCallback.call(self, click_event, move_event);
    },0);
  });
  jQuery(this).mouseup(function(){
     clearInterval(interval);
  });
  jQuery(this).mouseout(function(){
     clearInterval(interval);
  });
}

$(document).mousehold(function(click_event, move_event){
  $('#run').html(click_event.pageX+':'+move_event.pageX+', '
                +click_event.pageY+':'+move_event.pageY);
});
```

Comment: You are not invoking the function that is supposed to create the closure .. or you are *shadowing* a variable .. ?

Comment: @pst - What do you mean?

Comment: @pst nah, that wasn't it. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setInterval` does not pass arguments to the callback, so remove the `self` and `event` arguments. You don't "lose" the event in doing so.

```
$.fn.contmousedown = function(mousedownCallback)
{
    var interval,
        self = this;

    $(this).mousedown(function(event)
    {
        interval = setInterval(function()
        {
            mousedownCallback.call(self, event);
            console.log('on');
        }, 0);
    });

    $(this).mouseup(function()
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/9veUQ

---

> So how can I get a continuous update on the cursor position?

Use `mousemove` to capture the event.

```
$.fn.contmousedown = function(mousedownCallback)
{
    var interval,
        self = this,
        event;

    $(this).mousemove(function(e)
    {
        event = e;
    });

    $(this).mousedown(function ()
    {
        interval = setInterval(function()
        {
            mousedownCallback.call(self, event);
        }, 0);
    });

    $(this).mouseup(function()
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/dVaWS/

Comment: Yep this should do it.  The closure shares the local variables, no matter who deep you nest functions in that scope.

Comment: @MattBall - When I do this, my `$('#run').html` code only gets ran once. It updates to the first place I click, but doesn't track my cursor.

Comment: @Aust no; the code gets run over and over. It's that the event's coordinates aren't updated. Perhaps this is clarified with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/9veUQ/

Comment: @Aust it's getting run, the coordinates are just always the same.  Only a single mousedown event is created, at the coordinates that you click the mouse button down.  If you move the mouse while the button is down, that event wont be triggered again.  Perhaps you want `mousemove`?

Comment: @MattBall - Hmm, interesting. So how can I get a continuous update on the cursor position?

Comment: @Aust as Alex said, use `mousemove` to capture the event. I'll post a demo. Also, the post owner (that's me) is always notified when you comment on that post; you never need to `@username` them.